# Pass custom object to webservice from Android via KSOAP

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2

I have to call WCF web service from Android client.That web service method has it's own class (.net class object). How can I pass the customized (.net class object) as a parameter to the web service method.

Thanks in Advance...!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this tutorial [Complex objects with KSOAP](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html) , You have to implement 
KvmSerializable interface.